# How to use annotations (Actions) to authenticate/authorize user?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

In play framework 2, the zentasks sample shows how to do basic authentication. They subclassed Security.Authenticator and added additional methods for authorization. I find it a bit messy, since each method needs to be wrapped with an if-statement.

How can I convert [the methods isOwnerOf and isMemberOf](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Secured.java) into [Actions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaActionsComposition)? This would allow me to simply annotate the methods. Currently, I am struggling in create an annotation that would accept the param of the method. Even if I annotate the parameter, then I do not know how to fetch it when the Action is called.

If there's a better way, I would be glad to hear so.

Comment: Take a look at the [Deadbolt plugin](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) for the authorizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a ready to use full stack for authentication/authorization - [Play Authenticate](https://play-authenticate.herokuapp.com/)

- it includes Deadbolt
- it offers common providers like Facebook, Twitter, Goolge, etc
- it offers common password + own providers
- it supports multilanguage (also in informational mails)
- it includes ready-to-use Java sample